# How do I play all the song in a album when the user hit the album play button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services, react-native

Hi dear hoping you help me on this one  and also a big thank you for turning in to my question
I am working on a musical app I am using react-native and aws has my backend tools my problem is
I have a album and I will like to play the whole album  I mean all the song in the album if the user hit the album play button , below is my code for the db schema and the album button and the player Widget ...

Here is the code for the albumHeader

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, Image } from 'react-native';
import { TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import { Album } from '../../types';
import styles from './styles';


export type AlbumHeaderProp = {
    album: Album;
}

const AlbumHeader = (props: AlbumHeaderProp) => {

    const { album } = props;
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Image source={{ uri: album.imageUri }} style={styles.image} />
            <Text style={styles.name}>{album.name}</Text>

            <View style={styles.creatorContainer}>
                <Text style={styles.creator}>By {album.by}</Text>
                <Text style={styles.likes}>{album.numberOfLikes} Likes</Text>
            </View>
// This area is the play button I am talking about 
            <TouchableOpacity>
                <View style={styles.button}>
                    <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Play</Text>
                </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>

        </View>
    )
}

export default AlbumHeader;
```

Here is the SongListIem file

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import { Text, Image, View, TouchableWithoutFeedback, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

import styles from './styles';
import { Song } from "../../types";
import { AppContext } from '../../AppContext';

export type SongListItemProps = {

    song: Song

}

const SongListItem = (props: SongListItemProps) => {
    const { song } = props;

    const { setSongId, songId } = useContext(AppContext);


    const onPlay = () => {
        
        setSongId(song.id);


    }

    return (
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPlay}>
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Image source={{ uri: song.imageUri }} style={styles.image} />
                <View style={styles.rightContainer}>
                    <Text style={styles.title}>{song.title}</Text>
                    <Text style={styles.artist}>{song.artist}</Text>
                </View>
              
            </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    )
}

export default SongListItem;
```

Here is the player Widget

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Text, Image, View, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { AntDesign, FontAwesome } from "@expo/vector-icons";
import { API, graphqlOperation } from 'aws-amplify';

import styles from './styles';
import { Song } from "../../types";
import { Sound } from "expo-av/build/Audio/Sound";

import { AppContext } from '../../AppContext';
import { getSong } from "../../src/graphql/queries";

const PlayerWidget = () => {

    const { songId } = useContext(AppContext);


    const [song, setSong] = useState(null);
    const [sound, setSound] = useState<Sound | null>(null);
    const [isPlaying, setIsPlaying] = useState<boolean>(true);
    const [duration, setDuration] = useState<number | null>(null);
    const [position, setPosition] = useState<number | null>(null);






    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchSong = async () => {
            try {
                const data = await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(getSong, { id: songId }))
                setSong(data.data.getSong);
            } catch (e) {
                console.log(e);
            }
        }

        fetchSong();
    }, [songId]);

    if (song?.artist.length > 10) {
        song.artist = song.artist.substring(0, 6) + "...";
    }

    if (song?.title.length > 8) {
        song.title = song.title.substring(0, 5) + "...";
    }





    const onPlaybackStatusUpdate = (status) => {
        setIsPlaying(status.isPlaying);
        setDuration(status.durationMillis);
        setPosition(status.positionMillis);
    }

    const playCurrentSong = async () => {
        if (sound) {
            await sound.unloadAsync();
        }

        const { sound: newSound } = await Sound.createAsync(
            { uri: song.uri },
            { shouldPlay: isPlaying },
            onPlaybackStatusUpdate
        )

        setSound(newSound)
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        if (song) {
            playCurrentSong();
        }
    }, [song])

    const onPlayPausePress = async () => {
        if (!sound) {
            return;
        }
        if (isPlaying) {
            await sound.pauseAsync();
        }
        else {
            await sound.playAsync();
        }
    }

    const getProgress = () => {
        if (sound === null || duration === null || position === null) {
            return 0;
        }

        return (position / duration) * 100;
    }

    if (!song) {
        return null;
    }

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <View style={[styles.progress, { width: `${getProgress()}%` }]} />
            <View style={styles.row}>
                <Image source={{ uri: song.imageUri }} style={styles.image} />
                <View style={styles.rightContainer}>
                    <View style={styles.nameContainer}>
                        <Text style={styles.title}>{song.title}</Text>
                        <Text style={styles.artist}>{song.artist}</Text>
                    </View>

                    <View style={styles.iconsContainer}>
                        <AntDesign name="hearto" size={30} color={"white"} />
                        <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPlayPausePress}>
                            <FontAwesome name={isPlaying ? 'pause' : 'play'} size={30} color={"white"} />
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>
                </View>
            </View>
        </View>
    )
}

export default PlayerWidget;
```

Here is the AppContext

```
import React from 'react';

const context = {
    songId: null,
    setSongId: (id: string) => {

    }
}

export const AppContext = React.createContext(context);
```

This one is a bit boring but if you need the Schema here is it

```
/* tslint:disable */
/* eslint-disable */
// this is an auto generated file. This will be overwritten

export const getAlbumCategory = /* GraphQL */ `
  query GetAlbumCategory($id: ID!) {
    getAlbumCategory(id: $id) {
      id
      title
      albums {
        items {
          id
          name
          by
          numberOfLikes
          imageUri
          artistsHeadline
          albumCategoryId
          createdAt
          updatedAt
        }
        nextToken
      }
      createdAt
      updatedAt
    }
  }
`;
export const listAlbumCategorys = /* GraphQL */ `
  query ListAlbumCategorys(
    $filter: ModelAlbumCategoryFilterInput
    $limit: Int
    $nextToken: String
  ) {
    listAlbumCategorys(filter: $filter, limit: $limit, nextToken: $nextToken) {
      items {
        id
        title
        albums {
          items{
            id
            imageUri
            artistsHeadline
          }
        }
        createdAt
        updatedAt
      }
      nextToken
    }
  }
`;
export const getAlbum = /* GraphQL */ `
  query GetAlbum($id: ID!) {
    getAlbum(id: $id) {
      id
      name
      by
      numberOfLikes
      imageUri
      artistsHeadline
      songs {
        items {
          id
          imageUri
          uri
          title
          artist
          albumId
          createdAt
          updatedAt
        }
        nextToken
      }
      albumCategoryId
      albumCategory {
        id
        title
        albums {
          nextToken
        }
        createdAt
        updatedAt
      }
      createdAt
      updatedAt
    }
  }
`;
export const listAlbums = /* GraphQL */ `
  query ListAlbums(
    $filter: ModelAlbumFilterInput
    $limit: Int
    $nextToken: String
  ) {
    listAlbums(filter: $filter, limit: $limit, nextToken: $nextToken) {
      items {
        id
        name
        by
        numberOfLikes
        imageUri
        artistsHeadline
        songs {
          nextToken
        }
        albumCategoryId
        albumCategory {
          id
          title
          createdAt
          updatedAt
        }
        createdAt
        updatedAt
      }
      nextToken
    }
  }
`;
export const getSong = /* GraphQL */ `
  query GetSong($id: ID!) {
    getSong(id: $id) {
      id
      imageUri
      uri
      title
      artist
      albumId
      album {
        id
        name
        by
        numberOfLikes
        imageUri
        artistsHeadline
        songs {
          nextToken
        }
        albumCategoryId
        albumCategory {
          id
          title
          createdAt
          updatedAt
        }
        createdAt
        updatedAt
      }
      createdAt
      updatedAt
    }
  }
`;
export const listSongs = /* GraphQL */ `
  query ListSongs(
    $filter: ModelSongFilterInput
    $limit: Int
    $nextToken: String
  ) {
    listSongs(filter: $filter, limit: $limit, nextToken: $nextToken) {
      items {
        id
        imageUri
        uri
        title
        artist
        albumId
        album {
          id
          name
          by
          numberOfLikes
          imageUri
          artistsHeadline
          albumCategoryId
          createdAt
          updatedAt
        }
        createdAt
        updatedAt
      }
      nextToken
    }
  }
`;
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `setSongID(songID)` in your `SongListItem`, I would add to your context `setPlaylist([songID])`, then when they click on an album you would just do `setPlaylist([song1ID, song2ID, song3ID, etc.])`.  Then, you can do something like

```
const onPlaybackStatusUpdate = (status) => {
    setIsPlaying(status.isPlaying);
    setDuration(status.durationMillis);
    setPosition(status.positionMillis);
    if (status.didJustFinish) {
        // they finished playing the song, remove it from the playlist and 
        // then the next song should start automatically
        setPlaylist(playlist.slice(1));
    }
}

useEffect(() => {
    if (playlist.length !== 0) {
        setSongID(playlist[0]);
    }
}, [playlist]);
```

Comment: Sir I appreciate your help but your answer is still not clear could you elaborate more on it pls

Comment: Hi Sir I appreciate your answer but could you explain more on it please

Comment: I don't know what else to explain about it.  Code it so instead of setting a song id, you set the list of song ids to play.  When the list changes, you use useEffect to set the current song id to the first item in the list.  When current song id changes, you use useEffect to play the song.  When the playback status updates, check if `didJustFinish` is true, if it is, remove the first item from the list of song ids.